# Putting while loop inside Action Perform don't work in Java Webdriver?

Tags: selenium, while-loop, webdriver, action

I want to click multiple items in a table. I do this by using press n holding Ctrl and then clicking on multiple links using xpath. Now to click multiple xpaths I use while loop for how many links I want to click. But Im not able to so that inside a Action Perform  in Java. 
here is code that is showing error

```
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).  //syntax error on token".", ; expected.
while(items > 0)
{
click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div/div/div[`$items`]/div/div"))). //click(Webelement is undefined
}
keyUp(Keys.CONTROL). //keyUP is undefined
perform();
```

I have commented the errors I'm getting in the corresponding lines. It works fine if the while loop is removed. The problem only comes when while loop is added. Please help

Comment: Why do you like to select items in table? I think this is just UI help for user to make better copys in table (you are using Firefox right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is you probably want to have some Java programming tutorials before doing this. It won't take a long time, but you can probably avoid hours just trying to figure out some syntax errors.

I believe you copied this code somewhere else

```java
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click().keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();
```

Your logic is mostly correct, but did you know that Java statements end up with `;` rather than `.`, which is what error message "syntax error on token".", ; expected." means.

If you comment out the while loop, the code is the same with the line above, because it's a whole statement, ending with `;`. So there won't be any syntax errors.

```java
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).
// whatever in the while loop
keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).
perform();
```

When you add the while loop in, what you want is one statement to press down Keys.CONTROL, then a while loop to click, then a statement to release control. You can't just throw the while loop into one statement.

```java
new Actions(driver).keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).perform(); // end with semicolon
while(items > 0)
{
// wrong while loop logic, items will never change in the loop and what's $items?
// do you want a for loop with index? I don't think this locator is valid.
// however, the syntax error should be fixed.
new Actions(driver).click(By.xpath("//div/div/div/div[`$items`]/div/div")).perform(); // end with semicolon
}
new Actions(driver).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).perform();  // end with semicolon
```

Once you get rid of the errors, we can proceed to see it actually works or not.